# How to load UIWebView with an html page retrieved by NSURLConnect?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

How to load  UIWebView with an html page retrieved by NSURLConnect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSURLConnection` should give you some `NSData`. Then you can load these data into the web view with `-loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`.

(You can use `-loadRequest:` if you don't need to manipulate the data before loading.)

Answer (score 1):

```
responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error: &error];
NSString *htmlBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData 
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[webview loadHTMLString:htmlBody baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go with GCD: :)

```
   NSURL *urlObj = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlObj];

        [webViewObj loadRequest:request];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [webViewObj release];

        });

    });
```

Hope it helps.